# How to create new page in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My app displayed a grid of pokemons, I have retrieved the data from axios and fed it to a FlatList in React Native (Below)

[image]

I want each of these pokemons to be buttons which leads to the next page (Below)

[image]

I have no idea on how to do this. I'm assuming I have to create an 'onPress' function inside the Flatlist? Or React routing but not sure could someone shed some light into this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a lib to do that. I've been using React Navigation. You can follow its tutorial here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation